# How to auto-format code in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, formatting, format, code-formatting

How do you auto-format code in Eclipse?

Comment: how did you post a question with meeting the "quality standards". for me, it is a very simple question. i just wanted to know how you did that

Comment: It's a very simple question, but if it hasn't been answered yet then it is a question we need. So that when someone else has the same simple question they can come and find it here.

Comment: Will auto format applies to js files?

Answer (score 789, accepted):

**On Windows and Linux** : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

**On Mac** : <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>

(Alternatively you can press `Format` in Main Menu > Source)

Comment: Whats the up arrow on the mac?

Comment: @SSHThis it's the Shift key

Comment: I have some errors in my file. Can this be a reason for the above to not work??

Comment: These shortcuts won't work if you have errors in your file. On windows at least.

Comment: On Linux Ubuntu and Mint distros, ctrl + shift + f works as well. Thanks

Comment: PERFECTO, <- I have written this with a shift, btw. :D

Comment: Does anyone know where the settings for the autoformatter are stored (like a local XML file somewhere). I'd like to distribute a team-wide settings file for my group so there aren't any inconsistencies with formatting between different OSes.

Comment: The path in eclips (Version: 2021-06 (4.20.0)) is Main menu => Source=>Format

Answer (score 209):

Another option is to go to **Window->Preferences->Java->Editor->SaveActions** and check the **Format source code** option. Then your source code will be formatted truly automatically each time you save it.

Comment: A lot of options there it's really worth looking, also good to include the auto `@Override` statement on save

Comment: @HasanAboShally, now you just press two :D

Comment: This option can now be found in **Eclipse->Preferences->Java->Editor->SaveActions**

Answer (score 42):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> will auto format your code (whether it is highlighted or non highlighted).

Answer (score 22):

This can also be done at the Project Level:
In the Package Explorer, **right-click on the project > Properties > Java Editor > Save Actions**

This might be preferable when working as a team so that everyone's code is saved with the same format settings.

Answer (score 16):

Notice: It did not format the document unless I corrected all mistakes. Check your file before pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>.

Answer (score 14):

Press: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> or highlight the part of the code you wish to indent
and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>.

Comment: That's an `I` for "Indent".

Answer (score 12):

Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> save actions -> Format source code -> Format Edited lines (or) format all lines.

Some time when you work as a team, lead don't want you to format all lines of the code in a source file (Huge track changes will be there on commit). So, select 'Format Edited lines'. This will edit and format only the lines you modified.

Gubs

Answer (score 12):

You can do with the steps below

1. press <kbd>Ctr</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> (windows) or <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> (Mac os)
2. <kbd>Ctr</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> in windows or <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> in Mac os

It will auto format your code

Answer (score 9):

The secret is simple: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

Answer (score 5):

Also note that you can also "protect" a block from being formatted with **@formatter:off** and **@formatter:on**, avoiding a reformat on a comment for example, like in:

```
// Master dataframe
Dataset<Row> countyStateDf = df
    .withColumn(
        "countyState",
        split(df.col("label"), ", "));

// I could split the column in one operation if I wanted:
// @formatter:off
//    Dataset<Row> countyState0Df = df
//        .withColumn(
//            "state",
//            split(df.col("label"), ", ").getItem(1))
//        .withColumn(
//            "county",
//            split(df.col("label"), ", ").getItem(0));
// @formatter:on

countyStateDf.sample(.01).show(5, false);
```

Answer (score 4):

Update your IDE with the latest PDT version for better code formatting. 
On the main menu click **Help -> Install New Software** and then add the following URL in the **Work with** field:

```
http://download.eclipse.org/tools/pdt/updates/4.0.1
```

When asked for the name, give it `PDT4.0.1` and then move along with the update or install.

It will see if the appropriate PDT is already installed or if it is a lower version, which then would be updated.

After restarting or applying the changes go to **Windows -> Preferences**
on the side bar and expand **PHP -> Code Style**. Here you will see an item named **Formatter**. Select it and choose the active profile for the code formating. Thats it.

The next time you format it, it will choose a format according to the chosen active profile.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>

or

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

right-click on the project > Properties > Java Editor > Save Actions