# Format php code from within php

Tags: php, code-formatting

I would like to format the php files that I have in a directory, so that the code looks tidy and readable. I know how to do this via eclipse php, but is their a way to do several files in one go, via code?

Comment: there are bunch of "PHP Beautifier" websites that will do it for you....

Comment: dub http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15655126/how-to-auto-format-code-in-eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fabien Potencier (of Symfony fame) has written a small utility that can modify code to comply with PHPCodeSniffer defined standards for PSR-n - [PHP-CS-Fixer](https://github.com/fabpot/PHP-CS-Fixer)  - although it isn't perfect

Comment: Thanks, but is their another way without using Symfony?

Comment: This method doesn't require the symphony framework; it's a self-contained application that uses a couple of Symfony components that are included in the "bundle", automatically included via a composer install