# Type expected declaration or statement at end of input

Tags: c, loops, if-statement, syntax

I am making a C program that is a simple calculator without a GUI, called "Quical". (Check out the code on [Github](http://github.com/Emposoft/quical)). I am somewhat new to C, and so I am making some syntax errors. One of the errors is this:

```
expected declaration or statement at end of input
```

Another one of the errors that comes up is this:

```
else without a previous if
```

[Here is my code.](https://github.com/Emposoft/quical/blob/master/Calsrc.c)

Hopefully, this can shed some light as to why I am getting these syntax errors. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if it's an artifact from posting code on github, but you have quite a few statements after 'if' and 'else' that are not in blocks nor indented which I assume you don't want.

Comment: SO is a place for posting code, not links to code.  The actual relevant code should be directly in your question--for multiple reasons.

Comment: It may be a little messy. If you want to clean it up, I heartily request you file a pull request to the repo.

Comment: @nhgrif: I tried to do that, but the whole thing got messed up with formatting. It just seemed easier, and I already have the code there anyway.

Comment: Lines 84 and 117 there are else's lost(without if's). Why don't you use switch statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your braces don't match. You have something like

```
main()
{
   some statement
   {
   }

   another
   {
   }


and it ends.
```

It is saying it wants a statement here. Try that and see what the next error is.

Comment: Any chance you could push a pull request on the repository itself?

Comment: I could do it for you, but how would you learn? :-) What IDE are you using, if any? Most of them should be able to Beautify or format your code for you so it's easy to see unbalanced curly braces.

Comment: :) I am using Eclipse. Oddly, there is a "quick fix" feature, but it doesn't seem to correct the code automatically.

Comment: @JavaThunderMan See this link for how to automatically format it. This will help you see where braces are unbalanced.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15655126/how-to-auto-format-code-in-eclipse

Comment: Will try that link...