# Eclipse auto format code

Tags: eclipse

Is there anything in the preferences of Eclipse that would stop code formatting from working.

I've tried Ctrl+Shift+F and Source > Format but it does do anything

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15655126/how-to-auto-format-code-in-eclipse) maybe it will help.

Comment: Tried all that, not working - all the format does is line everything up on the left

Comment: What is your code language?  Eclipse does not have a formatter for every code language.

Comment: Do you have unresolved syntactic errors? What kind of file is it? Where is it located?