# Eclipse generates Java class filename conflict for inner classes

Tags: java, eclipse

I have two top-level classes; each has an inner class with the same name:

```
    **A.java**
    public class A
    {
    }
    class TestCase
    {
    }

    **B.java**
    public class B
    {
    }
    class TestCase
    {
    }
```

My expectation is that I will wind up with four class files, including A$TestCase.class and B$TestCase.class, which is what I get when I compile from the command line. Eclipse, however, just creates TestCase.class, and declares that "The type TestCase is already defined" when I try to compile B.java.

Is there an Eclipse option that I can set to produce (what I believe is the standard) A$TestCase.class and B$TestCase.class?

Thanks.

By the way, I am using Luna:
Version: Luna Release (4.4.0)
Build id: 20140612-0600

Comment: Why not declare a `TestCase` interface or abstract class and implement it for both `A` and `B`?

Answer (score 2):

Both versions of `TestCase` are top level classses. You need to create inner classes

```
public class A {
    class TestCase {
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, it's not an inner class (which is another question I've had for a while: what is it called?). Nevertheless, the Java compiler, invoked from the command line, produces A$TestCase.class and B$TestCase.class. How can I persuade Eclipse to do the same thing?

Comment: Eclipse will produce the same "dollar files" as the command-line compiler

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't do this for me. It creates an `A$TestCase.class` and a `B$TestCase.class`, as it should.

But this is only when they're actually inner classes... in your case, they're not really inner classes at all.

Answer (score 0):

TestCase is not an inner class as you might think, and this is why formatting code is essential when coding. check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15655127/1951298)