# Not printing perfect numbers

Tags: java, perfect-numbers

Here is my code :-

```java
package javaapplication;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class perfect02 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int i = 1, sum = 0;

        System.out.println("Enter maximum range : ");
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

        int a = kb.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter minimum range : ");

        Scanner kb2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int b = kb2.nextInt();

        System.out.println("perfect number in the given range are :");
        for (int n = b; n <= a; n++) {
            while (i < n) {
                if (n % i == 0) {
                    sum = sum + i;
                }
                i++;
            }
            if (sum == n)
                System.out.println(+n + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Why program is not printing perfect numbers ?

I have checked code many times but i am unable to find the solution .Please tell me what is going wrong in my code .Thanks in advance

Any help would be appreciated ....

Comment: Maybe this is to blame? `System.out.println(+n+ " ");` And please show the error

Comment: i am not getting any error

Comment: Eclipse is running my program properly

Comment: Please format your code using Eclipse's [auto format functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15655126/how-to-auto-format-code-in-eclipse) and get into a habit of doing that **whenever you make a change**. Remove all the unnecessary newlines. This is currently **completely illegible**.

Comment: You should consider using more meaningful variable names like `maxVal` and `minVal` instead of just `a` and `b`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, I looked into the perfect number generation and fixed it for you!

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter minimum range : ");
    int b = kb.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter maximum range : ");
    int a = kb.nextInt();
    kb.close();
    System.out.println("Perfect number in the given range are :");
    for (int n = b; n <= a; n++) {
        int sum = 0;
        int i = 1;
        while (i < n) {
            if (n % i == 0)
                sum = sum + i;
            i++;
        }
        if (sum == n)
            System.out.println(n + " is perfect");

    }
}
```

You should've had the sum and i variables declared inside the for loop, so they would be reset for each number!

Comment: @KetanGupta if this answer helped you  please upvote it and mark it as correct! Have a nice day!

Comment: Thanks Dude for help !