# Java Regex - replace all word except contain pattern

Tags: java, regex

For my case, I want replace all my code that contain character `;` to `;\n` but, I don't want to do it for  characters inside **for loop**.

```
int a=5;String B="";
for(int i=0;i<a;i++)
    System.out.println(i);
```

so, I want result like this :

```
int a=5;
String B="";
for(int i=0;i<a;i++)
    System.out.println(i);
```

I have no idea how to make it.

Comment: you can check for lines that start with word for and skip those lines

Comment: Why are you using regex and even Java regex for that? Most IDE's can do that out of the box and they are likely to do a better job than regex

Comment: @Vivek Mishra : can u make some example?

Comment: @Manos Nikolaidis : please, i want to make application so that make it easier for my project

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to do it something like this:- **When you find the index of for** then next **find index of right parenthesis** ")"and **then jump that much indexes.**

Answer (score 0):

```
B.replaceAll(";", ";\n")
```

this will replace all instances of `;` with `;\n`

Comment: how to inside for loop?

Comment: for loop would be a bad idea as we are replacing 1 character with 2. replaceAll takes care of that internally. if we have to do it then everytime we find the ; we have to shift all the remaining characters by 1 place to make room for the \n

Comment: so what should i do for my case?
do you have best way beside regex.

Comment: there is a way to do this using lists. can you provide some sample input?

Answer (score 0):

No need to use regex for this task. Any IDE(example Eclipse) and even some text editors can do this task for you. Use regex for manipulating text not your program code. [Click here to see how this would be done in eclipse.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15655126/how-to-auto-format-code-in-eclipse)