# Why is word wrap not working on eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm currently using eclipse Mars and I'm trying to figure out how to enable word wrap so that when my lines are too long, it can go down to the next line. I tried going to

Preferences > Java > Code Style > Formatter

and I created a new eclipse profile then set the maximum line width to 50 under the 'line wrapping' tab. I applied the feature and clicked 'Ok'. I tried to test if it worked by writing a really long line of code and it still didn't wrap. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just apply the format to a file or files, look at this for hotkeys: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15655126/how-to-auto-format-code-in-eclipse

Comment: did you actually applied the format, or just defined it? (50? I hope that was a test value?)

Comment: If you could add a screenshot of your `Line Wrapping` tab that would help. Also make sure you set `Line Wrapping Policy` to a policy other than `Do not wrap`

Comment: I did apply the format and set the Line wrapping policy to 'Wrap where necessary'. It still doesn't wrap the way I want it to. Do I need to set the maximum line width to a lower number?

Comment: Are you actually running the formatter (Source > Format)?

Comment: I have defined maximum line length as 120, and when i apply formatting, I do not see the line wrap. Does any one have solution for this?

Comment: Strangely, it seems like line wrap max length is a bug in **Eclipse Oxygen**. I tried to apply line wrap in **Eclipse Neon 3**, and its working fine :O