# removing all beginning white space in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Is it possible to remove all white space at the beginning of a line/s?

Sometimes, when I copy and paste code, there will be a mixture of tabs and spaces which upsets the spacing format I already have. So it would be great if there was a way to delete all the starting white space so I can re-indent it myself.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you can un-indent code in Eclipse by selecting it and hitting/holding <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Alternatively you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> to re-indent or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> to re-format your code based on your formatting settings (see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15655126/how-to-auto-format-code-in-eclipse)).

But that may depend on the Editor for the type of code/document you're working on.

Comment: I already know about the shift + tab, but the ctrl shift f really helped. Though I think I'm still looking for the magic "remove all leading white spaces" button.

Comment: @A.Lau Did some research and I'm afraid there's no default feature in Eclipse for what you're looking. There's [one for trailing whitepaces](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/10/08/how-to-deal-with-whitespaces-in-the-eclipse-ide/), but none I could find for leading whitespace.  There may exist a plug-in which provides the desired functionality, but I don't know any. Personally I use [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) (Menu Edit / Blank operations) for text-operations like that.

Comment: Thanks anyhow. I'll just use the ctrl shift f and make due.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a linux computer you can use this command:

```
$ cat input.txt | sed 's/[ \t]*$//' > output.txt
```

Comment: Not quite what I want as I might insert it into the middle of a text document and stuff. And I'm using the Eclipse as my IDE