# How can we replace tab character with white space for existing Java code in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, code-formatting

I am using Eclipse - mars. I need to replace tab character with white spaces in existing code. I did this:

```
Open Window->Preferences from menu bar.
Select Text Editors from tree menu.
Uncheck Insert spaces for tabs.
```

But this doesn't replace for existing code. Is there any simple way to do that, considering I have some 25 java files to do this.

Comment: Try formatting your existing code in eclipse.

Comment: @LukeMelaia: How do we do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15655126/how-to-auto-format-code-in-eclipse

Comment: seems duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/407929/how-do-i-change-eclipse-to-use-spaces-instead-of-tabs

Comment: @Chinmay He's having a problem with applying it to his java files, not changing the settings.

Comment: @LukeMelaia: This solution i have tried, but this create lots of extra space in variable declaration statement. Before and after "=" operator.

Comment: Then change your code style formatter to remove white spaces before and after assignments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you have changed your settings, you need it to be applied it to your code files. This can be done by formatting your code.

- Windows: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> (Control + Shift + F)
- Mac: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>
  (Command + Shift + F)
- Main menu: main menu > Source > Format

(from the answer [How to auto-format code in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15655126/how-to-auto-format-code-in-eclipse))

---

As [@StephaneM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2294428/stephanem) suggested:

> Change your code style formatter to remove white spaces before and after assignments

To remove the whitespace before and after assignments (`=`).

Answer (score -1):

I did this:

- Edit -> Find/Replace
- Tick "Regular expressions"
- In "Find" put "\t" (without quotes)
- In "Replace with" put four spaces
- Click "Replace All"
- Repeat for each file

I did this because when I do "Ctrl+Shift+F" as in the accepted answer, it messed up other parts of my indentation. For example I had multiple-indented builder pattern statements (for builders which have sub-builders) and it changed them all to single-indentation.

Comment: Replace All works only from spaces to tabs, not the other way around. Not all tabs are the same width, so it screws up column-aligned code