# How to remove redundant spaces in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I found this line of code in my program:

```
        inPorts.put(myInPort,  new HashMap<String, Object>().put(otherOutPort,  otherDevice));
```

where in front there are to tabs, that's ok, but after the comma and before the word `new` there are two spaces by accident. And before the word `otherDevice` there are also two spaces.

Is it possible to remove one space (in this case) automatically?

Comment: Have you tried the to reformat using STRG+ALT+F ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to auto-format code in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15655126/how-to-auto-format-code-in-eclipse)

Comment: As an aside in Java 9 onwards you can use `Map.of` instead of `new HashMap<String, Object>().put`

Comment: `⌘` `SHIFT` `F` is not what I am searching for. My code will be reformatted automatically when I save it. I am looking for a setting where I can remove redundant spaces.

Comment: I don't know of any setting that just removes extra spaces immediately.

Comment: Needn't be "immediately". It's fine when it will remove them on file save or `⌘` `SHIFT` `F`

Comment: @greg-449 Thank you, but I use Java 8